# Convert text cells to DATE, but leave empty and DATE cells intact

Tags: spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

sorry for my ignorance I have no idea about spreadsheets.

What I have is a column that contains dates but they are there in different format
some are text like '19.12.2006 and others are cells that are formated as a date like 2009-10-10

I want them all to be date cells, so I found a formula =DATEVALUE

What I done is I put =IF(A2="";"";DATEVALUE(A2))

For the dates in text format it done well, for empty cells it's ok as well, but when the cell is a date cell I have Err: 502

Can anyone please help me?

[image: here's what it looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, `DATEVALUE` expects a string that looks like a date, not an actual date. However, there is nothing stopping you from taking your dates and converting them to strings with `TEXT`. The right *format mask* can distinguish between dates and string dates for you.

[image: CALC DATEVALUE with TEXT]

The formula in N1 is,

`=IF(ISBLANK(M1); ""; DATEVALUE(TEXT(M1; "mmm dd, yyyy;@")))`

This formats anything that is an actual date into a string date and leaves any string dates alone. There seemed to be a *dd/mm/yy* vs *mm/dd/yy* issue between your sample data and my regoinal system so I used that complex date format but just about any date format will do. The **@** is stuck on the end to catch strings. The result is processed by `DATEVALUE`. I used `ISBLANK` for the second test but there is nothing wrong with `IF(M1=""; ...`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a user of OpenOffice Calc, but in Excel and Google Sheets there is a formula called =IFERROR() which can be used in this scenario - your formula in N7 would be:

```
=IFERROR(IF(M7="","",DATEVALUE(M7)),M7)
```

Otherwise, you could use IF() with ISERROR() as follows:

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(M7)),M7,IF(M7="","",DATEVALUE(M7)))
```

Hope that helps!

Mike